# Is $No^2$ or $(\mathbb{R}^*)^2$ rotation invariant?

Tags: complete-spaces, nonstandard-analysis, surreal-numbers

The fields of the surreal and hyperreal numbers aren’t complete. I’ve noticed that $\mathbb{Q}^2$ isn’t rotationally complete as $(0,1)$ could be rotated to a point not in the rational plane (like $(1,1)/\sqrt{2}$). This is because the field itself isn’t metrically complete and I’m wondering if this causes $No^2$ or $(\mathbb{R}^*)^2$ to have the same issues or if the incompleteness is such that it isn’t (I’m thinking of how two intervals of the real line form an annulus as the surreal and hyperreal lines are made of many connected components).

So given the two planes, are they invariant under rotations like the standard Euclidean plane is?

Comment: For any field $\mathbb F$, the plane $\mathbb F^2$ is rotationally invariant, if only elements of $\mathbb F$ are allowed in the rotation matrices. Your example of $\begin{bmatrix}1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\\-1/\sqrt2&1/\sqrt2\end{bmatrix}$ obviously doesn't have rational numbers. You really need to define "rotation" first.

Comment: By “rotation”, I mean a special orthogonal matrix except the sine and cosine functions are there extended form instead of their real counterpart. They’d of course act on the space by treating points as column vectors.

Comment: You don't need sines and cosines. A special orthogonal matrix is just $A\in\mathbb F^{2\times2}$ where $A^TA=I$ and $\det A=+1$.

Comment: I see two possible questions concerning two definitions of special orthogonal matrices: If $a^2+b^2=1$ where $a,b\in\mathbb F$, then does there exist $\theta\in\mathbb F$ such that $\cos\theta=a$ and $\sin\theta=b$? Conversely, if $\theta\in\mathbb F$, then are $\cos\theta,\sin\theta\in\mathbb F$ also?